# Solr 7 id unique key of type Integer

Tags: solr

I have in my database id field of type integer.

I want to index those is Solr 7.

I get "Error CREATEing SolrCore 'mycore': Unable to create core [mycore] Caused by: uniqueKey field (id) can not be configured to use a Points based FieldType: pint

That I get it, though. How can I specify id transformation so that I add document with id being of type integer, but it converts it and index it with type string.

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't work straight out of the box? I.e. make the id field a string field and add an integer, it should convert it automagically if I remember correctly.

Comment: I have never heard of the FieldType "pint"

Comment: @MatsLindh it does, thanks! (only caveat I can see is that the docs query give back doesn't convert back values to int. You get the string. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kellyfj As of Lucene7 the numeric types where mostly switched over to be backed by the new Point types, and pint is the default name for the integer implementation for this in the example schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work as you want it to by using the `string` type. It'll convert the integer when it has been submitted, and should work as you expect it to.

As noted the only caveat is that the returned type is a string as well, so if you're parsing a format that has serialized the type as well (such as JSON or POJO), the type returned will be a string.